# SVN shows the wrong icon, what is wrong?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Somebody had commited source code to svn server. My local svn project icon should be red exclamation mark.But it's green checkmark in fact.

（1） I have never commit my source code to svn server.
(2) My  svn client is TortoiseSVN 1.7.11

what is wrong?  Thanks!

Comment: Actually TortoiseSVN does not check for the updated versions of the files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I see, you don't understand how Subversion works (i.e. the meaning of working copy status in particular). I strongly suggest reading [SVNBook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.basic.version-control-basics.html#svn.basic.working-copy) as well as [TortoiseSVN Manual](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-basics-svn.html#tsvn-basics-svn-workingcopy) to learn about Subversion and version-control in general.

Subversion working copy is your *private workspace*. It represents the data stored in the repository, you can modify the data and commit it back as the new revision to the repository.

Subversion working copy does not fetch any changes from the repository automatically. So if someone has changed files in the repository by committing new revision, you have to update your working copy to fetch these changes. As well, you can look through commit notification emails you get or check `svn log`.

Remember to update your working copy before doing the commit!

Comment: There is a possibility to check the updates for the specific files by means of SVN client but it needs establishing the connection on every icons refresh, it is not used by TortoiseSVN which checks only local files status